How can I close with macros, the Display View Frame in Catia Drawing
I have a drawing and a sheet. In this sheet I have a isometric view and its Display View Frame is active. I want to deactive with macro. I try recording but there is no code. So do you know how can I do it?
When I click to run Macro, it should deactive.

Please check the FrameVisualization property of the view. Or you talking about the print area of the sheet?

I am talking the orange area of the view. I want to delete it.

So switch the FrameVisualization property to false
